# Is a vector of lists really a vector?

Tags: c++, list, memory, vector

Not a code problem, but I finished a program that saves a vector of lists, but I suddenly thought... If the elements a vector are contiguous in memory, but a list needs pointers because it isn't contiguous memory.
A vector of lists is actually contiguous, if its elements are not? (In C++ language).

Comment: In C++: it will probably be implemented as a vector of pointers to lists.  The pointers will be contiguous.

Comment: What language is this? The meanings of "vector" and "list" vary a lot more than you might expect between languages.

Comment: Also, please read [ask] then edit your question to include which language you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, it was implemented in C++, (I am sorry, I am new to this world of programming and forums)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it just means the the vector elements are of type list and the data for these elements are contiguous in memory. However, "inside" the list elements there may be pointers to other memory locations. In essence, not everything that is *referenced* in vector elements  is contiguous in memory but the references themselves are.

Answer (score 0):

> A vector of lists is actually contiguous, if its elements are not?

Yes and no.

From the vector's perspective it's still contiguous. The immediate data of every element, every `std::list`, is contiguous.

But that's just its internal pointers and such. In turn every actual element of each `std::list` is hidden away behind another layer of indirection.

So the ultimate *data* is not stored contiguously.

> Is a vector of lists really a vector?

Well, that depends on what you mean by "vector" and how strict you want to be with that definition.

Welcome to abstractions!

Comment: I accidentally assumed C++. Still, probably a fair bet.